# grep only returns No such file or directory

Tags: grep

Apparently I've done something that has altered how `grep` runs on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Regardless of what I input to it, it returns "No such file or directory", or something along those lines.

For example, if I create a file and then try and search it with `grep`, it doesn't work. Entering the two commands below produces the error.

```
$ echo 'dog eat dog' > dog
$ grep 'd' dog
grep: d: No such file or directory
```

Perhaps I've done something so that `grep` is looking in the wrong place?

Comment: What return `alias grep` ?

Comment: `alias grep` returns `bash: alias: grep: not found`

Comment: @BagusTesa apologies for posting in the wrong spot.

Comment: Problem solved. I had removed `/bin/grep` from the path variable by accident. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I mis-typed the previous comment. Basically, there is an alias for `grep` in `.bashrc` that is commented out, and when it gets un-commented then `grep` breaks. I will move this to the AskUbuntu as he requested.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you try it this way

  `echo 'dog eat dog' > dog; /bin/grep 'd' ./dog`

  If this works, your aliasing or other bashrc settings a wrong
- Do you have write and read access in the directory where you call the command?

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct - something seems wrong with your environment

```
$ echo 'dog eat dog' > dog
$ grep 'd' dog
dog eat dog
```

Your error message suggests that it is considering "grep: d: " as a command and not "grep". The other possibility is that you do not have grep in the path. Try:

```
which grep
```

To find out where grep is installed. Also try a non-existing command such as grepx (which does not exist) to check your error message:

```
$ grepx 'd' dog
-bash: grepx: command not found
```